# Angular js, on select element i want to POST data to save it in the database then i want to update it with PUT without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, angularjs, ng-options

I have a table which had a select field in it which I'd like to save into database if it dosnt exist yet through POST data. If it does exist then I'd like to update the already existing row in the database.
This can be found in the tbody in which i have my tablerow with an ng-repeat to display all data from a json.

```
<td>
  <select id="statusSelect{{anime.id}}" ng-model="statusId" ng-options="animeStatus.id as animeStatus.status for animeStatus in animeStatuses"
      ng-change='addUserAnime( "<?php echo Yii::app()->user->id; ?>", anime.id, statusId )'>
  </select>
</td>
```

Next this is my code for what im trying to do in the angular controller:

```
$scope.addUserAnime = function( userId, animeId, statusId, userAnime )
{
    if ( userId == '' ) {
        //alert user that he/she needs to log in first
    } else {
        //loop through my json where i saved from which user which anime is saved with which status
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.usersAnime.length; i++) {
            //if there is an already existing entry then i want to update it if not then i want to introduce it into DB with POST
            if ($scope.usersAnime[i].anime_id == animeId && $scope.usersAnime[i].user_id == userId) {
                $scope.userAnime = $.extend({}, $scope.usersAnime[i]);
                $scope.userAnime.status_id = statusId;
                $scope.userAnime.date_modified = today;
                saveUserAnime();
                return;
            }
        }

        $scope.userAnime = {
            id: 0,
            user_id: userId,
            anime_id: animeId,
            status_id: statusId,
            rating: '',
            date_modified: today
        };
        saveUserAnime();
    }
};
```

Problem is that if i POST a new entry it gets saved in the database, but if i dont reload the page and i change the select again giving it a new option it gets POSTed again instead of using PUT for update.In the end i end up with two entries instead of one. I want to introduce it to database on first select and i want to update it if its changed after. Is that possible. I tryed doing it with $dirty using the table as form but thats a nono.
In the saveUserAnime() function its correctly deffined to use POST if its new entry and use PUT if its an existing one. I have another form for which it works. The problem must be in this current function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that code where you get the object with the animeStatus and put that in a function and call it directly after that. Now you can call that function when your POST is done, so the new data will be loaded.

Otherwise you could also check through SQL, if that value exists in your table, so you don't need your check in angularjs, that would be easier than this one.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?  As a side note I'd like to add that in saveUserAnime function I got a function which does post data if id is 0 which happens when its new entry and it uses put when it has a proper id.